# double typed DependencyProperty not causing MeasureOverride() to be called

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm making a custom tick bar indicator, derived from the `FrameworkElement` class.  And I have a bunch of properties (with accompanying dependency properties) defining the look and functionality of the indicator, e.g. `Orientation` and `Range`.  `Orientation` is of type `Orientation`, and `Range` is of type `double`.

Changing `Orientation` from the view model causes the `MeasureOverride()` method to be called, allowing me to define the new dimensions of the control.  But for some reason, changing the `Range` property doesn't (and neither does changing other `double` typed properties).  And I can't figure out why.  Anybody know why this is, and how to get the `Range` property to also call `MeasureOverride()`?

```
public class DepthIndicatorTickBar : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Orientation", typeof(Orientation),
            typeof(DepthIndicatorTickBar),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Orientation.Horizontal,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RangeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Range", typeof(double), 
            typeof(DepthIndicatorTickBar), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((double)100, 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public Orientation Orientation
    {
        get { return (Orientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OrientationProperty, value); }
    }

    public double Range
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(RangeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RangeProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MeasureOverride");
        // Calculating new size
        return size;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnRender");
        // Drawing control
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting AffectsRender when there is AffectsMeasure?

Comment: Hmm..  All are set to AffectsRender, so that's probably part of the problem.  But then why are some dependency properties calling MeasureOverride() and others are not?

Comment: Setting RangeProperty to AffectsMeasure causes MeasureOverride() to be called, but now OnRender() isn't called so the control isn't redrawn.  How can I get it do to both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure that a value change of your dependency property forces a measure pass and re-rendering, just combine the appropriate `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions` flags:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RangeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Range),
    typeof(double), 
    typeof(DepthIndicatorTickBar), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        100d, 
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. :-)